# Entity Framework Generate from Database Generates Empty EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've tried following some simple tutorials to get started with Entity Framework using the AdventureWorks databse.  I'ved tried this several times and I get the same results.

1. Create a Class Library
2. Add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model
3. Choose Generate from Database
4. Create a connection to the AdventureWorks DB
5. Choose all the Tables and Views

Results: Generates a Blank EDMX that tells me to drag items from the Model Browser.
When I look at the Model Browser, there is nothing there to drag to the EDMX.

Any ideas what I can try?

Using SQLServer 2012 Express
Visual Studio 2012 Express (.NET 4.5)

Comment: It's a known issue with mapping the adventureworks database. The Production.Document table has a column with a data type that EF does not recognise. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143541/adventureworks-cant-create-ado-net-entity-data-model

Comment: You can remove the table, but if you include the views and sp's, the edmx file will throw a thousand of errors... convert and overload exceptions....
It's a real mess with EF to work

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. 
My table was lacking a primary key. 
Adding one did the trick for me : the table appeared in the .edmx